# Python str comparison differs between console and within function

Tags: python, string, string-comparison

There appears to be a difference in the way boolean str comparisons are made between console (I think correct) and within a function (I think not correct). i.e. I get a different answer for the same code and data.
console:

```
s
Out[537]: ['a', 'g', 'xyz', 'b', '6', 'g', 'v']

'x' in s
Out[538]: False

'xyz' in s
Out[539]: True
```

So this all makes sense now, within a function I take each element of s in turn and look for a True return as follows;

```
def f(s):
    print 's in f(s) looks like: ', s, 'x' in s
    return 'x' in s
```

Result:

```
Number of required string in list of strings is:  s sent to f(s) is:  a
s in f(s) looks like:  a False
s sent to f(s) is:  g
s in f(s) looks like:  g False
s sent to f(s) is:  xyz
s in f(s) looks like:  xyz True
```

So why is it returning True on 'xyz' if i'm looking for 'x'?

Comment: Can you please print `s` in `f(s)`?

Comment: It seems you have a list in the first example, not a string. The last does not contain the string "x". But obviously the string "xyz" contains the character "x".

Comment: Your function checks whether `"x"` is in the string `s`. When you call `f("x")`, `s` is set to `"xyz"`, so you're checking `"x" in "xyz"`. The string `"xyz"` does contain the string `"x"`.

Comment: Yes at the top of my question in the console I have s = ['a', 'g', 'xyz', 'b', '6', 'g', 'v']

Comment: I would agree that 'x' is contained within 'xyz' but that doesn't explain why  x in s returns False at the console (which is what I want the function to do). Or maybe there is a better way to compare?

Comment: You are testing whether the string `'x'` is an element of the list. It is not. The elements are `'a', 'g', 'xyz', 'b', '6', 'g'` and `'v'`. No `'x'` here. *"which is what I want the function to do"* You want `'x' in 'xyz'` to return `False`? Why? What is the logic behind that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the console you test:

```
'x' in ['a', 'g', 'xyz', 'b', '6', 'g', 'v']
```

In your program you test

```
'x' in 'xyz'
```

In other words you are not comparing like with like. Both expressions evaluate the same way at the console and in a program.

---

The first comparison above tests if a string is contained in a **list**. The second tests if a string is contained in a **string**.

These are quite different things. In the former you require that one of the strings in the list is exactly equal to `'x'`. In the latter, you check whether or not the letter `'x'` can be found inside a string.

---

You did not show how you called your function but we can deduce what you did. You wrote something like this:

```
for str in ['a', 'g', 'xyz']:
    f(str)
```

The confusion seems to arise because you think that you passed the entire list to `f()` but you did not. You iterated of the list and passed each item to `f()`, one after the other.

I suspect that your naming is not helping. You named your list `s`. But you also named the argument to the function `s`. So that inside the function `s` refers to the argument passed, a string, but outside the function `s` refers to a list.

In the long comment trail you argue as though your code was:

```
f(['a', 'g', 'xyz'])
```

But this is not the code that you wrote.

---

The main thing that you should accept is that the difference in behaviour is due to a difference in coding. You should learn to trust that the console does not evaluate expressions differently. Once you trust that, you'll react to such symptoms by looking at your code rather than thinking the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: That is the last element I send to the function which returns True instead of false (at least the way I'm expecting). In this test I'm looking for 'x'. So I send it s[0] which is 'a'. it returns False,  good; then 'g', False good; then 'xyz'. It returns True. Not so good. Doing the same thing on the console returns False for 'x' in 'xyz'

Comment: @djee No it doesn't. You'll find that `x in 'xyz'` is `True`. Everywhere.

Comment: @dje: `'x' in 'xyz'` returns `True` in the console. I seems like you simply want to compare two values. Then you should use `==`, not `in`.

Comment: I checked again, and in the function it is;

Comment: @dje Can I refer you to the two expressions in my answer. May I ask if you agree that they are different?

Comment: I checked again, and in the function it is; return 'x' in s (s being the list of str)

Comment: @dje Please see my previous comment. And regarding your latest comment, in the function `s` is not a list. It is a string.

Comment: @dje: You are not calling the function with a list of strings. You are calling the function for each element in the list, i.e. you are passing strings to the function, not a list. If you call `type(s)` in the console and the function, you will see that they are different types.

Comment: Sorry for all the trouble, with regard to David's comment, I'm looking for 'x' in s not in 'xyz'. Console output as I said before is 
Out[537]: s = ['a', 'g', 'xyz', 'b', '6', 'g', 'v']

'x' in s
Out[538]: False

'xyz' in s
Out[539]: True

Comment: @dje: Right, but you **are** passing the **string** `'xyz'` to the function, effectively doing `'x' in 'xyz'`. If you don't want that, pass a list to the function, not a string. If you'd post the code where you call the function it would be easier to point this out.

Comment: @dje Please can you answer the question. Do you agree that the two expressions in my answer are different? Because these are the expressions that you are evaluating. The issue lies with your code. The interpreter is fine. Once you can accept that then you can begin to look at your own code in a critical light.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. So if I check a list of strings, It will compare to the whole string within an element,  not a substring that matches. If I compare to a single element of type string, it will compare to any substring that matches. Thanks!

Comment: @dje Glad you got there. My nugget of advice is to trust the interpreter. When you can't understand behaviour of code, first of all suspect that the problem is in the code. It's highly unlikely that you'll find defects in the interpreter until you are a very expert and experienced programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, *isn't* `x` in the string `xyz`? :)

Python regards strings as enumerable containers of single-character strings (Python has no character type). So according to Python the element `'x'` *is* in the container `'xyz'`.

I'm sure that if you evaluate `'x' in 'xyz'` in the prompt it will return `True`.

Comment: I did try that as shown in the first part of my question. It returns False as expected.

Comment: @dje no you did not do that. `'x' in 'xyz' == True`

Comment: Mmmm... not quite you didn't. :) You searched for the element `'x'` in the container `['a', 'g', 'xyz', 'b', '6', 'g', 'v']`, in which case the whole string `'x'` needs to match one of the list's elements.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're probably invoking this implies that you're passing across strings instead of using the list.  It doesn't help matters that you've also used the same variable `s` inside of your function, either.

Let's suppose you do one of two things:

- Use a different variable name in the function

  This has the added benefit of not masking `s`, and will return what you expect when you check `'x' in s`.

  ```
  def f(v):
      print 's in f(s) looks like: ', s, 'x' in s
      return 'x' in s
  ```

  An acute disadvantage is that the variable `v` is quite useless, and should *probably* be used in place of `'x'`.
- Explicitly pass in the list instead of relying on the list's predefined state

  This has the added benefit of not relying on a local/global variable that is subject to whimsical change.

  ```
  def f(v, li):
      print 'li in f(s) looks like: ', li, v in li
      return v in li
  ```